# How can I use a XAML trigger to say great-than-or-equal-to a value?

Tags: xaml, triggers

I can create simple triggers that check if a **property has a specific value** like this:

```
<Style x:Key="StatusIndicator" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="off">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But how would I use any **more complicated operators**, e.g.:

*PSEUDO-CODE:*

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Amount}" Operator=">=" Value="35">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Is there some property like "Operator", or do I need to use a converter for this or **how are complex operators realized in triggers**?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have complex operators in triggers. A converter is a good way to go; perhaps from int to bool for your example, or int to enum if there are mare than two states.

I don't think you'd want to embed complex logic in XAML. It wouldn't take long to become a maintenance nightmare.